# Forcing table rows to appear on the same line using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a two-row table like this:

```
---------------------------
| 1 Item | Total: $370.00 |
---------------------------
|   View Cart   Check-out |
---------------------------
```

I want it to display inline, like this:

```
| 1 Item | Total: $370.00 | View Cart   Check-out |
```

Is this possible with CSS?
Note: Unfortunately this code is produced by my CMS and it would be difficult to change it to use divs and then CSS float:left or display:inline-block.

Simplified HTML:

```
<table class="cart-block-summary">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="cart-block-summary-items">1 Item</td>
   <td class="cart-block-summary-total">Total: $370.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cart-block-summary-links">
   <td colspan="2">View cart  Checkout</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Given the presentational requirements, are you *sure* that this is, in fact, *tabular data*? Perhaps a list would be a better fit?

Comment: yeah david's right. since you want it to float left using an un-ordered list would be best.

Comment: i agree, however i don't want to re-write my cms code if i can help it. i prefer a css 'hack'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Worked for me:

```
   ​​table { width: 600px;}
    tr{float:left}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N5fhU/

Comment: On a side note, IE7 is not gonna like that I believe.

Comment: Sorry, didn't check it in browsers. (chrome only)

Comment: Thanks. It works in Chrome and IE8... I'll have to test out IE7.

Answer (score 0):

You could also remove the last TR that way it will look all in one line

```
<table class="cart-block-summary">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="cart-block-summary-items">1 Item</td>
   <td class="cart-block-summary-total">Total: $370.00</td>
   <td class="cart-block-summary-links" colspan="2">View cart Checkout</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```